# Consumir servicio WCF en Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, wcf, c#-8.0

Estoy utilizando *WCF* para crear un servicio.

*DataContract*:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using ConnectionPG.Classes;

using Npgsql;

namespace MyHouseService.Services.User {

    [DataContract]
    public class User {

        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string NickName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool LogicalDelete { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public static void SetUser(User obj, NpgsqlDataReader rs) {
            obj.Id = CFunctionsBd.CargarInt(rs, "id");
            obj.NickName = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "nickname");
            obj.FirstName = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "firstname");
            obj.LastName = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "lastname");
            obj.Password = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "password");
            obj.BirthDate = CFunctionsBd.CargarDateTime(rs, "birthdate");
            obj.LogicalDelete = CFunctionsBd.CargarBoolean(rs, "logicaldelete");
            obj.Email = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "email");
            obj.PhoneNumber = CFunctionsBd.CargarString(rs, "phonenumber");
        }
    }
}
```

La clase `CFuncionesBD` se encarga de realizar peticiones a la base de datos y manejar los datos devueltos por esta de forma genérica.

*ServiceContract*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace MyHouseService.Services.User {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWSUser {
        [OperationContract]
        bool ExistByEmail(string email);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ExistById(int id);

        [OperationContract]
        List<User> GetActives();

        [OperationContract]
        List<User> GetAll();

        [OperationContract]
        bool Insert(User obj);

        [OperationContract]
        User ReadById(int id);

        [OperationContract]
        bool RemoveById(int id);

        [OperationContract]
        bool Update(User obj);
    }
}
```

Implementación:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using ConnectionPG.Classes;

using MyHouseService.Exceptions;

using Npgsql;

namespace MyHouseService.Services.User {
    public class WSUser : IWSUser {

        private NpgsqlConnection connection = CConnection.Instancia.Conexion;

        public bool ExistByEmail(string email) {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @email AND logicaldelete = FALSE";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteExist(cmd);
        }

        public bool ExistById(int id) {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id AND logicaldelete = FALSE";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteExist(cmd);
        }

        public List<User> GetActives() {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE logicaldelete = FALSE";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteSelectList<User>(cmd, User.SetUser);
        }

        public List<User> GetAll() {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteSelectList<User>(cmd, User.SetUser);
        }

        public bool Insert(User obj) {
            if (!ExistByEmail(obj.Email)) {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname", obj.NickName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", obj.FirstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", obj.LastName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", obj.Password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", obj.BirthDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logicaldelete", obj.LogicalDelete);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", obj.Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", obj.Email);
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (nickname, firstname, lastname, password, birthdate, logicaldelete, email, phonenumber) " +
                                  "\n VALUES \n" +
                                  "(@nickname, @firstname, @lastname, @password,@birthdate, @logicaldelete, @email, @phonenumber)";

                return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            } else {
                throw new ExceptionExistEmail(obj.Email);
            }
        }

        public User ReadById(int id) {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = @id AND logicaldelete = FALSE";

            User user = new User { Id = id };

            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteSelect(cmd, user, User.SetUser) ? user : null;
        }

        public bool RemoveById(int id) {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users \n" +
                              "SET (logicaldelete = TRUE)\n" +
                              "WHERE id = @id";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
        }

        public bool Update(User obj) {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand { Connection = connection };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", obj.Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname", obj.NickName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", obj.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", obj.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", obj.Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", obj.BirthDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logicaldelete", obj.LogicalDelete);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", obj.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", obj.Email);
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users \n " +
                "SET (nickname = @nickname, " +
                    "firstname = @firstname, " +
                    "lastname = @lastname, " +
                    "password = @password, " +
                    "birthdate = @birthdate, " +
                    "logicaldelete = @logicaldelete, " +
                    "email = @email, " +
                    "phonenumber = @phonenumber)\n " +
                "WHERE id = @id";
            return CFunctionsBd.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

*Exception*:

```
using System;

namespace MyHouseService.Exceptions {
    public class ExceptionExistEmail : Exception {

        public ExceptionExistEmail(string email) : base(string.Format("El Email ya existe {0}", email)) { }
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar este servicio para probar las funciones de consulta a la base de datos funciona correctamente.

Lo publico en *localhost* en *IIS* y hago referencia al servicio publicado desde mi proyecto *Xamarin Forms* y al ejecutar el programa corro automáticamente las siguientes líneas:

```
WSUserClient client = new WSUserClient();
client.OpenAsync();
User user = client.ReadByIdAsync(1).Result;
client.CloseAsync();
```

La declaración y asignación de la variable user va al servicio, el cual va a la base de datos y debería devolver los datos del usuario en la base de datos con el *ID 1*, el cual existe. Pero cuando va a buscar al servicio, la funcion `ReadById()` me lanza el siguiente error:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 'System error.'
```

Actualizacion:

Si ejecuto el servicio desde *Visual Studio* me abre mi *navegador web* con esta página:

[image: Las instrucciones para probar un servicio.]

En cambio, si navego al servicio desde *IIS*, el navegador que me abre es completamente blanco.

Comment: estas seguro que cuando levantas la App tu servicio sigue corriendo? Ese error es que no encuentra el endpoint disponible

Comment: En principio si

Comment: esta bien, lo tenes activo, deberias probarlo primero para estar seguro de que todo anda bien. con WcfTestClient, ahi te pide la direccion del servicio y te va a mostrar los metodos disponibles para poder consumirlos y chequear que todo anda bien

Comment: De todo modos creo que deberias exponer tu servicio para consumilor como Rest y enviarle Json como Get o Post, para disminuir el envio y recepcion de datos moviles.

Comment: Okay, gracias por el consejo mas adelante lo pasare a REST. Al probar el servicio todas las funciones funcionan perfectamente, pero al ejecutarlo lanza ese error. Puede ser que porque este en localhost el emulador del teléfono no pueda verlo? haciéndole inaccesible el endpoint?

Comment: Acabo de crear una aplicación de consola para probar si es inaccesible por ese motivo y todo apunta a que si es por ese motivo. En la aplicación de consola funciono perfectamente me trajo los datos. De ser este el caso como puedo hacer que el emulador vea el localhost?

Comment: Podes probar usar tu libreria con alguna api disponible en web, creo que es tu api el problema, siempre uso HttpClient.

Comment: Revolviste el problema?

Comment: No, Al final opte por crear un servicio REST con Nodejs y express. Cree una maquina virtual con ubuntu e hice deploy allí